# Use selenium to click a link based on input [python]

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I have made a program with selenium to go to my schools website, sign in, and get the whole text with a CSS-selector and print it out. It then prints out all the available exams. However, there is a download link next to every exam, and Im trying to make it possible to create an input with the exam name, and then make selenium click that particular download button connected to that exam.

Im dont know to much about HTML so I'll try to be as clear as I can.

Here are the code and some pictures:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://minatentor.hv.se/minatentor/')

username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#userNameInput')
password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#passwordInput')

username.send_keys(r"my_username")
password.send_keys('my_password')

password.submit()

tentor = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#examTable > tbody')
print(tentor.text)
browser.close()
```

This is the website looks. I used a CSS-selector to get this text and print it (`'#examTable > tbody'`).

[image: This is how the website looks.]

This is what it prints in the shell.

[image]

This is how the inspector looks.

[image]

I used the CSS-selector of the `<tbody>` to get the whole text. Every `<tr>...</tr>` is a row which is marked on the picture. "Hämta" means Download in swedish so that is the download button.

Im want to be able to to write an input with the course name ("Kursnamn" in the picture) and make selenium press the download button that is associated with that course name. Like this:

[image]

Is that possible? I hope I made it as clear as possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't tested cause didn't have the HTML, but it looks something like this.

```
s = raw_input("Kursnamn?")
download_item = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[contains(text(), '+s+')]//a[@href]')
```

Then

```
download_item.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Strangely it didnt work with the course name "GRUNDLÄGGANDE REDOVISNING", but with the course code "GLR100".

Comment: Yes Sir, take care with this kind of characters, dont use diaeresis, accent marks etc. in XPATH!! And care with the text input appears multiple times